# How configure webpack to parse <script type="module">

Tags: javascript, webpack

I know the most common scenarios to build a web project with webpack is using HTML page with "classic" `<script>` tags ([html-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/)) or a source JavaScript file as entry point but I received an old web project to be built with a source code and structure that I can't change. The project structure looks like this:

```
project
  |- app
      |- js
      |- index.html
  |- node_modules
      |- types
  |- package.json
```

The entry point is `index.html` which looks like this (included only the meaningful pieces):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/importmap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>

    <script type="module">
      import * as TYPES from 'types';
      import {MyFactory} from 'js/classes/Factories.js';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is pretty much like HTML page entry point with classic scripts as I mentioned above except the script of type "module" which is not parsed by webpack. So

**How can I configure webpack to parse all module sources inside the `<script type="module">`?** (`types`, `Factories.js`, etc.)

Note that hypotetical module `types` was installed with `npm` so it's located in `node_modules` folder. This is resolved now with `importmap.js` which injects `<script type="importmap">` with the resolution. I guess I won't need `importmap` mechanism anymore after build the project successfully.